# auto_link shows plain text HTML in view - Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use auto_link in order to generate the clickable url:

```
<div> 
  <%= auto_link("Go to http://www.rubyonrails.org") %>
</div>
```

In the view page, it is supposed to show

Go to http://www.rubyonrails.org

However, it actually shows the HTML code in plain text:

```
Go to <a href="http://www.rubyonrails.org">http://www.rubyonrails.org</a>
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Rails version is 3.0.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default auto_link returns sanitized html_safe strings. This behaviour can be overriden setting the :sanitize option to false

```
  <%= auto_link("Go to http://www.rubyonrails.org", sanitize: false) %>
```

Comment: I tried but I still got the plain html code in view. However, inspired by that, I tried `auto_link("Go to http://www.rubyonrails.org").html_safe` and that works! If you have an idea why, I am happy to accept it as the answer :)

Comment: Yes That's because in Rails 3, erb will default to not allow any ruby output to contain html. To get around this you have to use `html_safe` everytime you need to output html

Answer (score 0):

It's working as intended, see https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink (which replaces the function that was removed in Rails 3.1)